# Oversight AI Woodcutter behind a Chum

Tags: android-netrunner

I am the runner and on a run I encounter a [Chum](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/chum-core), but I don't break its subroutine.

I encounter the next piece of ICE which happens to be a [Woodcutter](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/genesis/cyber-exodus/woodcutter-cyber-exodus) (rezzed with an [Oversight AI](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/genesis/a-study-in-static/oversight-ai-a-study-in-static)) without advancement counters and thus no subroutines. I pass it.

Have I broken all subroutines on the Woodcutter?

- If yes, I don't get three netdamage from Chum and the Woodcutter is trashed alongside the Oversight AI.
- If no, I get the three netdamage from Chum and Woodcutter is not trashed.

I heard that you don't take the damage, and that Woodcutter is not trashed. But why should it be like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At one point there was a rules ruling via e-mail that it wouldn't be trashed to OverSight AI, and separately that Chum wouldn't do the damage. In the latest [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf) It has been clarified that this didn't make sense, and so for consistency "all" would apply to "0" and so all the subroutines are broken, and so chum does not do damage and oversight AI means the ice is trashed.

> **“All”**
>
> The word “all” includes the number zero.
>   Example:
>   The Corporation plays an OversightAI
>   and rezzes a Woodcutter. The Runner encounters the Woodcutter while it has
>   zero subroutines. The Runner is considered to have broken all the
>   subroutines on the Woodcutter, and the ice is trashed.

(Previously, it was decided that since there were no subroutines the number broken was unknowable and so effects wouldn't trigger, but that gets rather confusing rather quickly with rules effectively throwing null pointer exceptions!)

Comment: +1 Good answer, detailing the original ruling and how it caused confusion, followed by the later FAQ rules clarification